# Eclipse becomes really slow after opening jquery.min.js

Tags: jquery, eclipse

As the title says,anytime I open a long minified version any javascript library like jquery or foundation.min.js, my eclipse installation becomes very very sluggish. Sometimes after a restart, things become normal again until I open these files. 
Is there anything wrong or is there some tweaking I could make to improve this situation?
Eclipse version is

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Kepler Release
Build id: 20121114-2344
```

Im using Ubuntu linux

Comment: It sounds like it's trying to parse the minified code, maybe for code coverage or something? If you use a non-minified file, does it still happen?

Comment: I've seen Visual Studio hang if a large minified file has no line breaks. I imagine the same could be true for Eclipse.

Comment: Maybe it is due to the long lines. In minified files all code is on a handful of lines, sometimes even a single line. Do you have wordwrap on? If so, that may make it harder for Eclipse to redraw the code on your screeen.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder once in a while you want to take a look at a js library, for example to see the version and such.

Comment: I believe it has to do with the many codes per line but then even after closing the that file, eclipse continues to be sluggish sometimes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to exclude this file from all validators.

Project Properties -> Validation -> click the settings button -> create or edit exclude group.

Furthermore, do Properties -> JavaScript -> Include Path -> Source -> edit excluded.

Comment: Won't this disable validation of my own custom javascript edits?

Comment: No, not if you only exclude the external *.min.js files. You can either exclude entire folders or individual files. Try it, there are all the options you need.

Comment: As soon as I click the settings button Eclipse hangs ;(

Comment: Only changing the Include Path (second step) did the trick for me. As soon as I wanted to click the settings button in Properties -> Validation (first step) Eclipse hangs.

Comment: @shawndreck validation of javascript files on eclipse is of absolutely no use to a developer.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use minified files in development. Use build scripts to minify/uglify/concatenate you js assets on production, but for development purposes use non-minified versions.

If you really think you have to open minified javascript files with full-blown IDE like Eclipse, try to switch off any code analyzing, syntax highlighting options you have. It can be really hard for IDE engine to parse long single-line files while analyzing its content, and I dont think that highlighted syntax will help you much with minified js

Comment: Thank you for the advice. So basically this is a case of prevention rather than solution

Comment: Actually I needed to do this because I was working on a simple "js minifier" PHP project of mine.

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging around and decided to try a different plugin ,specifically [Amateras Javascript Editor] to open/edit javascript files. Then I changed the default javascript editor to this plugin and its things are much better.

Now Eclipse behaves normally after open and/or editing minified javascript files.

Thank you all who helped !