# Searching in Visual Studio 2013, 2015 hangs when results are in minified files (single long line)

Tags: visual-studio

We have a web project with Angular, jquery and Telerik Kendo.

When searching for any text `Ctrl+Shift+F` that is then found in any of their `*.min.js` or `*.js.map` files, the VS (both 2013 and now 2015) will become unresponsive for 30-60s. Also when later I scroll the `Find Result 1` window, it will momentarily become unresponsive when long line becomes visible. Everything becomes smooth again if I clear the search results from `Find Result 1`.

We have the `*.min.js` and `*.js.map` files included in project itself. Is this wrong approach?

Answer (score 8):

This is a well known problem, the Connect feedback article [is here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/794640/find-and-result-not-work-well-with-minified-file).  These files are poison pills to an IDE, compare to [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080068/eclipse-becomes-really-slow-after-opening-jquery-min-js).

Little to add, beyond not adding them to your project, the proposed workaround in the article is the obvious one.  And as long as you *need* to search through these files you surely want to work with the non-minimized versions of them.

Comment: Hi, The Connect issue is about usability, can't find mentions about VS actually freezing on them. Also can't find any "best practice" articles from credible sources for just run-of-the-mill web project that isn't using "npm/grunt/whatever". We have access to nuget, msbuild and tfs. What I mean is that I can't locate any credible source on how this should be handled in real life instead of some basic happy-case-blog-example.

Answer (score 2):

In the Find options, expand "Result options" (Alt+S) and enable "Display file names only". The contents of the files will not be displayed in the find results and everything will be a lot faster. You can still double click a file name in the find results to go to the exact location of the match in that file.

Answer (score 1):

Does this problem happen for everyone, or only on particular machines? Are there any Visual Studio extensions that may be slowing down the search? You could try and temporarily disable all extensions and see if you have the same problem.

Otherwise, I would agree that including the .min.js and .map files in the solution / project is not ideal anyway.

My recommendation is to use [Bower](http://www.bower.io) to manage your 3rd party client-side library dependencies. They say use the right tool for the job, and in this case, it's currently Bower.

Bower support is baked in to Visual Studio 2015. Here's some Microsoft docs on using Bower in Visual Studio 2015:
http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/bower.html

Docs for installing Kendo using Bower: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/install/bower

Now, this by default will put those vendor libraries in a bower_components folder under the project root. You would then not include this folder in your project, or in source control (but bower.json and optional .bowerrc would go into source control).

This should alleviate your problem in VS2013, but in 2015, Find in Files will still search bower_components. So your best bet is to try and narrow down the source of the slow-down.

Using Bower potentially impacts your development and build process, so you might want to avoid that if that's going to force your hand to make other changes you're not positioned for yet.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can check to try and help solve this issues, is in your gruntfile's `minify` task, make sure the `mangle` property is set to false. Mangle changes the variable names to really short names, so sometimes that can mess up your other files that use variables from those minified files, and other errors can occur. I'm not sure why visual studio crashes or wouldn't be able to handle searching for a string that doesn't exist, but it's something to consider.